# Why is returning a list faster than appending to a return variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my mind using a return variable rather than using the return statement means you should skip a copy of the list. It's not as readable but I thought it would be faster.

so I tested it:

```
import timeit

TEST_DATA = 10000000
ITERATIONS = 1000

time_taken = timeit.timeit(
"""
def get_big_list(test_data):
    return [random.random() for _ in range(100000)]

return_list = get_big_list(test_data)

""",
setup='import random; test_data ={0}'.format(TEST_DATA), number=ITERATIONS)

print("return_list", time_taken / ITERATIONS)

# ----------------------------- SECOND TEST -----------------------------------

time_taken = timeit.timeit(
"""
def get_big_list(test_data, return_list):
    [return_list.append(random.random()) for _ in range(100000)]

return_list = []
get_big_list(test_data, return_list)

""",
setup='import random; test_data ={0}'.format(TEST_DATA), number=ITERATIONS)

print("return_list", time_taken / ITERATIONS)
```

I was really surprised by the numbers I received and I don't understand why the return statement is faster.

```
$ python large_list_return.py 
('return_list', 0.013130356788635254)
('return_list', 0.022573610067367553)
$ python3 large_list_return.py 
return_list 0.016797171516984236
return_list 0.02749005461903289
```

Another interesting thing I found was that it was faster to use a for loop to append than it was to use a list comprehension.

```
time_taken = timeit.timeit(
"""
def get_big_list(test_data, return_list):
    for index in range(100000):
        return_list.append(random.random())

return_list = []
get_big_list(test_data, return_list)

""",
setup='import random; test_data ={0}'.format(TEST_DATA), number=ITERATIONS)
```

returned these numbers

```
python large_list_return.py 
('return_list', 0.0133241708278656)
('return_list', 0.019642770051956176)
python3 large_list_return.py 
return_list 0.017075919962022453
return_list 0.024502045304980128
```

Comment: Objects are passed by references.. and are not copied. Also... Python lists are supposed to be stored in continuous memory blocks. I think python uses the policy of allocating memory equal to double/four ( not sure ) times of current size of list, and whenever the current size exceeds the allocated size... a reallocation and copying of whole list occurs... That's why the appending method is much slower compared to others.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think it would be faster to capture the return value of a bunch of `append` calls in a list comprehension.  You are building up a giant list of `None`s that you then throw away.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is faster with `return` because the first example is accessing the global namespace for the `return_list` variable. Better to keep it in a local namespace, inside the function. Excuse any errors I made in this comment, I am not very brushed up on Python internals, but I do think it's because of the namespace.

Comment: Nah, the only avoidable namespace access is `random.random`, which could be yanked into a local.  On my laptop, that does speed up the first example from 17 to 12 milliseconds:-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't make copies unless you explicitly ask for a copy (e.g by taking a **slice** of a list) -- you just get another reference to a list that's been created anyway.

`append` on the other hand may need to get more memory and copy the previous contents -- it's amortized O(1), but it's still a lot more work.

Moreover, since you use a list comprehension for what should be a loop:

```
[return_list.append(random.random()) for _ in range(100000)]
```

in your second implementation you're **also** creating another list (which then you're tossing away), one make up of a hundred thousand occurrences of `None` (the return value from `append`.  That's why the `for` is faster there -- it avoids uselessly creating that redundant list.

If you're looking for optimizations, consider **hoisting** namespace lookups, as I mentioned above in a comment.  Specifically, using:

```
def get_big_list(test_data):
    r = random.random
    return [r() for _ in range(100000)]
```

on my dated laptop, this takes 12 milliseconds vs your first version's 17 (which tells us that each `random.random` lookup takes about 50 nanoseconds).